# Scrollbar growing on hover

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

On a landing page, I want to have a centred logo, then below, 3 images with border side by side and a little bit of padding. When you hover over any those 3 images, the text on that image slides to the bottom and becomes enclosed in a box. I also want the page to be restricted to 100% of the browser window, no scrolling, at least on desktop. On tablet or mobile, I want them to stack.

For the most part, I have it working. I have the text sliding effect, and it stacks correctly on smaller devices, but I have some issues.

I cannot seem to restrict the page to 100% of the browser window on desktop. There is always a little bit of vertical scrolling needed to see the bottom of the 3 images.

Also, when you hover over an image, the scrollbar grows longer. The hover code is obviously not quite correct because it is pushing the whole overlay box down. I also want to enclose the text in a coloured box on hover, but when I try to add a background, or border, it encloses the entire overlay element. I am not sure how to shrink the text element so that it will be centred in the image, but only be the size of the text so I can style it further.

If anyone can help me out, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
    <style>
        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 0;
            transition: .5s ease;
        }
        .cols {
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .cols:hover .overlay {
            bottom: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .cols img {
            border: 10px solid #332b2a;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        p {
            color: white;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
            font-weight: 800;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-align: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .imageCentre {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 20%;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        .logo {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .col-xs-6 {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="imageCentre" alt="Logo"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 cols">
                <a href="http://url.com" accesskey="l">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <p>TEXT 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 cols">
                <a href="http://url.com" accesskey="c">   
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <p>TEXT 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 cols">
                <a href="http://url.com" accesskey="o">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <p>TEXT 3</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="Image 3" />
                </a>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
body
   {
     height: 100vh;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Sadly not, I still get a bit of cropping in the bottom of the image.

Comment: Try chaining the size of your images as well. so add something like ` max-height: 20vh;` to `img` in CSS

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have solved that particular issue. Thanks.